# How to categorize returning users into different time buckets based on the frequency of their visit

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

So I've a visit_log table which essentially tracks multiple user_visit to the app. It has user_id and timestamp as a column. I've been able to aggregate the user_visit data such as that now I know how many weeks, biweek, month, quarter & year user has visited the app  using the following logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ,user_id
                ,count( distinct date_part('year', timestamp) * 100 + date_part('week', timestamp)) as week
                ,count( distinct date_part('year', timestamp) * 100 + ceiling(date_part('week', timestamp)::decimal/2)) as biweek
                ,count( distinct date_part('year', timestamp) * 100 + date_part('month', timestamp)) as month
                ,count( distinct date_part('year', timestamp) * 100 + ceiling(date_part('month', timestamp)::decimal/3)) as quarter
                ,count( distinct date_part('year', timestamp)) as year
     FROM visit_logs
```

Now I want to take this one step further & define the users as weekly, biweekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly & rarely returning users such that they follow 80% of the threshold across all the buckets, to clarify if a user returns to the app more than 80% of the time during a week in the selected time range then he is weekly user & so on.

Below is the SQL code that I tried to take it one step further & replicate the above Python logic:

```
, temp AS 
(
      SELECT 
              user_id
              ,SUM(week) * 0.8 as total_weeks
              ,SUM(biweek) * 0.8 as total_biweek
              ,SUM(month) * 0.8 as total_months
              ,SUM(quarter) * 0.8 as total_quarters
              ,SUM(year) * 0.8 as total_year
      FROM  time_count
      GROUP BY 1
)


,week_count as 
(
            SELECT CASE WHEN week > total_weeks THEN 'Weekly'
                        WHEN biweek > total_biweek  THEN 'Biweekly'
                        WHEN month > total_months THEN 'Monthly'
                        WHEN quarter > total_quarters THEN 'quarterly'
                        WHEN year > total_year THEN 'yearly'
                        ELSE 'rarely' 
                    END as time_bucket
            FROM time_count
            LEFT JOIN temp ON temp.user_id = time_count.user_id
                           
)

SELECT * FROM week_count
```

Not sure where am I going wrong but it just doesn't seem to work as expected. Please advise/assist at your earliest convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little befuddled.  I would approach this using window functions.  Here is an example with built-in time-frames:

```
select user_id,
       (case when num_weeks > 0.8 * total_weeks then 'weekly'
             when num_months > 0.8 * total_months then 'monthly'
             when num_years > 0.8 * total_years then 'yearly'
             else 'rarely'
        end) as frequency
from (select user_id,
             count(distinct date_trunc('week', timestamp)) as num_weeks,
             count(distinct date_trunc('month', timestamp)) as num_months,
             count(distinct date_trunc('year', timestamp)) as num_years,
             extract(day from current_date - min(timestamp)) / 7 as total_weeks,
             extract(year from age(min(timestamp, current_date))) * 12 + extract(month from age(min(timestamp, current_date))) as total_months,
             extract(year from age(min(timestamp, current_date))) as total_years
      from visit_logs vl
      group by user_id
     ) vl;
```